# Wordpress permalinks no longer work after site migration

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, xampp, permalinks

After a site migration, the home page of new site url loads, but the permalinks all redirect to Apache's(i'm on XAMPP stack) default page:

```
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

localhost
Apache/2.4.16 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1p PHP/5.5.28
```

I don't think this is wordpress db issue. otherwise, I would've gotten wordpress's default page not found page.  What else is causing this?  Is there a .htaccess file somewhere that needs to be modified?

**EDIT**
I used this script for the db migration:  https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

**EDIT**
So added the default .htaccess from https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess, and it redirects to xampp's homepage.  So that officially means the permalink structure somewhere in wordpress db/routing is broken(not routing properly).  My new site url is "localhost/somewebsite", where "localhost" is default domain name of my xampp/local dns setup.

Comment: Hmm, what is the structure of the permalinks in the db and what should they be? I wouldn't assume that the permalinks haven't changed/dragged baggage with them if you have a new url and|or folder structure.

Comment: well thats the thing, i still want the same permalink structure, just with with the new site address.

Comment: oh sorry, but where can i find permalink structure in db?  which table/field is it?

Comment: Yes i already updated the SiteURL and HomeUrl fields in wp options table.  In fact i used this script:https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Comment: right, i did a migration about a month ago and had problems. They got sorted, but to prove that things weren't lost, I changed the permalink settings in the WP admin dashboard to default, so `http://example.com/?p=123`. Try that and see if they come back. If not, you have more serious problems, methinks.

Comment: thats the thing i don't have admin section accessible as of now, because it is after a page in wordpress site.

Comment: `example.com/wp-admin/` is the default. if you didn't change it, it'st still there. if you put it a level or two down from root, add them, e.g., `example.com/level1/level2/wp-admin/`

Comment: nope didn't work, instead it still shows the above page, and the link changes to:  login-2/?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fsomewebsite%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1

Comment: did you say you changed the wp admin url? If you did this in a plugin / theme remove the theme/plugin from the folder so you can get in and then go to permalinks and resave. It should be working then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. You have to make a virtual host for your site. Here are the 4 steps you have to do:

1. Go to C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf and make two new hosts. First set up a localhost so that when you want to call another folder which is no virtual host work:

```html
#localhost
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:/XAMPP/htdocs"
  ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost> 
#My Website
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:/XAMPP/htdocs/my-website" #your path to your installation
  ServerName my-website.dev #Change my-website to your wish name/url
  ServerAlias my-website.dev #Change my-website to your wish name/url
</VirtualHost>
```

2. Go to the Windows hosts file and add this:

```html
 127.0.0.1  my-website.dev
```

3. Go to your Wordpress .htaccess file and paste this into it:

```html
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

You have to save all files and restart your Apache and MySQL Server

4. Now you have to change all Worpdress url's in your database to `http://my-website.dev` (its a sample! You've to paste the url you set in the xampp host file here). To make this step easy you've to download the Database Search and Replace Script in PHP from `https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/`. Unzip this and paste the folder `Search-Replace-DB-master` in `C:/XAMPP/htdocs`.
   Open your browser and go to this url: `http://localhost/Search-Replace-DB-master/`. Now enter your database informations in the database section (db-name, user, passwort). Go to the top and enter in the `replace` field your old url (in my situation: `https://my-website-old-url.com`) and in the field after `with` your new url (example: `http://my-website.dev`).

Now click on live run in the middle of the page and all of your old urls will replaced with the new one.

It may be that you have to set AllowOverride to **All** in your httpd-conf file. You also have to check that **LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so** in your httpd-conf has no # infront of it because of rewriting etc...

Finaly go to the browser and enter your new url: my-website.dev

Thats it! Hope I can help you with this.

Answer (score 1):

A few things can go wrong here.

1. Try go to your admin page and reset your permalink by saving the default permalink before changing back to your original permalink. This is because during migration the permalink used seems to get screw up and needs reset 99% of the time especially if u have woo commerce installed.
2. Check that that mod rewrite is enable on your server
3. Make sure your .htaccess file is the default to avoid other rules from conflicting with the default ones in the new environment

I don't think it's your database issue as well. Do try it and let us know how it go!

Comment: Thanks for the response.  1) I cannot access admin, as that is a page in the site technically, 2) mod_rewrite is enabled(phpinfo() displays),3)there is no .htaccess in root of wordpress site.

Comment: I think you got the answer, the .htaccess did not migrate over? If so, add it in with the default rules as shown on https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess

Comment: ya please look at update to my question.  it did not solve the issue.

Comment: if im not wrong, you migrated your official website with a domain to your localhost environment? If that's the case, all you need to do is to go to your hosts file and change the domain name to your local ip so that you can go to your backend and reset your permalink.

Comment: i c, so where is the hosts file in xampp install for windows 7?

Comment: also why would i need to edit host file for this?  i mean i'm still using "localhost/somewebsite" as the main domain.